# Best load balance hardware

Tags: networking, load-balance

I have to buy a load balance to manage two adsl lines (ADSL 2), on a company with a huge number of users.
This device will have at least 3 wan port (for a new future adsl line), and gigabit lan.

Which load balance hardware can I buy for my purpose?

I have seen tp-link TL-ER5120, but I'm not sure it is able to manage all the traffic of my network.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [Elfiq hardware](http://www.elfiq.com/products) for this.
This is a link balancer. You will still need a router/firewall behind it.